# ReactNative Importing with ... fail's

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have three files

1. ***Block.js*** import data with es6 import shown belowe.

   ```
   /*
   COMPONENTS IMPORTS.
   */
   import BlockPill from '../../../components/block/pill.js'
   import BlockNavigation from '../../../components/block/navigation.js'
   import BlockFooter from '../../../components/block/footer.js'

   /*
   EXPORTS
   */
   module.exports = { BlockNavigation, BlockFooter, BlockPill }
   ```
2. ***instance.js*** imports block.js as shown below and export using spread operator.

   ```
   /*
   COMPONENT EXPORTING
   */
   import Blocks from './core/registration/block.js' // custom: @blocks component imports.

   /*
   EXPORTS.
   */
   module.exports = {
     // tags.
     ...Tags,

     // mods.
     ...Mods,

    // block.
    ...Blocks,

    // pages.
    ...Pages
   }
   ```
3. ***welcome.js*** import instance and use block as follow.

   ```
   /*
   IMPORT START.
   */
   import Instance from '../../../system/instance.js' // custom: application component's store.

   let { BlockPill } = Instance || {}

   // component.
   <BlockPill />
   ```

RESULT: react-native displays red screen showing following message.if I remove  than code works else fail.

**MESSAGE:** *Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for componsite components got undefined...*

Answer (score 0):

The import for `BlockPill` does not work. You are setting it to an empty object in case when `Instance.BlockPill` is falsy (`let { BlockPill } = Instance || {}`), that is where the error message is likely coming from.

When you export modules in common.js style, you must use `require` to import it.

```
// instance.js
const Blocks = require('./core/registration/block.js');
module.exports = {
    ...Blocks 
}

// welcome.js
const Blocks = require('../../../system/instance.js');
let { BlockPill } = Blocks; // Blocks is always defined, no need for default object.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing es6 imports with previous version exports, so I'm not sure but you should try:

```
import * as Block from './core/registration/block.js' // instance.js

import * as Instance from '../../../system/instance.js' // welcome.js
```

and export your components as follow:

```
// block.js
export BlockNavigation;
export BlockFooter;
export BlockPill;
```